# Wireless Speakers For the Whole House - Do they exist?

Tags: speakers

Does anyone know if there are speakers that you can hook up to a HTPC\Media Center and then take the speakers anywhere around the house to listen to them?

Basically, what I've found has either been headphones that do this or wireless speakers that site on the desktop.

If they do exist, is there a special name for them or particular brand?

**I'm not looking for shopping advice, I just want to know if hardware like this exists**

p.s. - I'm aware of FM transmitters, that isn't really what I'm looking for.

TIA.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [shopping recommendation questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are not welcome. See [how to ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) too, there are plenty of results and reviews out there on [Google](http://www.google.com).

Comment: I looked on google, newegg, anandtech, etc but could not find what I was looking for. This isn't my first time on superuser, but I was not aware of this limitation. I think the problem is how I worded it. Frankly, I have yet to come across a good answer for any of my questions on superuser.com - yet I love SO. Perhaps I just don't know how to ask the hardware geeks the question properly :P I will rephrase the question, thanks.

Comment: +1 Much better like this. :-)